# Stop VBA simplifying a fraction and keep the format

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I'm trying to use VBA to put together two numbers with a "/" between them and a leading zero but it keeps simplifying the fraction rather than keeping the format I have set.

[image: Live Coding]

```
Sub for_live_code()
    
    StartRow = 2
            
    Do Until Range("AT" & StartRow).Value = ""
        If Range("AR" & StartRow).Value < 100 Then
            Range("AQ" & StartRow).NumberFormat = "0#/0#"
        Else
            Range("AQ" & StartRow).NumberFormat = "0##/0#"
        End If
        Range("AQ" & StartRow).Value = Range("AR" & StartRow).Value & "/" & Range("AS" & StartRow)
        
                
    StartRow = StartRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

How do I stop the fraction being simplified and keep the formatting? Also, it is giving a decimal number in the formula bar and if it is not a whole number it is not keeping the first zero.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-numbers-as-fractions-0121ecac-1773-4f2d-8cd3-7db51fd83b77) it says

> If you don't need to perform calculations on fractions, you can format
> a cell as text before you type a fraction into it by clicking Text in
> the Category list. This way, the fractions that you type will not be
> reduced or converted to decimals. However, you cannot perform
> mathematical calculations on fractions that are displayed as text.

So, I guess, the following code does what you are after

```
Sub for_live_code()
    Dim StartRow
    StartRow = 2
            
    Do Until Range("B" & StartRow).Value = ""
        '        If Range("C" & StartRow).Value < 100 Then
        '            Range("A" & StartRow).NumberFormat = "0#/0#"
        '        Else
        '            Range("A" & StartRow).NumberFormat = "0##/0#"
        '        End If
        Range("A" & StartRow).NumberFormat = "@"  ' Text Format
        Range("A" & StartRow).Value = Format(Range("C" & StartRow).Value, "00") & "/" & Format(Range("B" & StartRow), "00")
        
                
        StartRow = StartRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Not quite, as this doesn't use my logic statements of a leading zero up to 100. This drops the zero from 10 upwards.

Comment: You could change that by adding an if statement again, right?